# Delete multiple images from aws

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is the code I am using for deleting the multiple images from aws

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
})

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET
  }
})
```

This is the arrray I am passing from the front-end to delete images

```
const array = [
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/lgfit/picture/5b55a7a6c316686bbbbc8120.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/lgfit/picture/5b4c3ca0097c915e38d0d21515-09-2018_12_13_48.jpg'
]
```

Here I am passing images in `deleteObject` of aws

```
var options = {
  Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
  Delete: {
    Objects: [{
      Key: array
    }],
  }
}
return new Bluebird((resolve) => {
  s3.deleteObject(options, function (err,data){
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data)
  })
})
```

And I am getting following error

```
{ MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Key' in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Delete' found in params
    at ParamValidator.validate (/home/user/ashish/FitnessApp/Fitness-New-one/fitnessapp-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:40:28)
    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/home/user/ashish/FitnessApp/Fitness-New-one/fitnessapp-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:108:42
```

Please help what I am doing wrong here!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.

1. You are using wrong SDK method.
2. You are passing parameters in wrong format.

`deleteObjects` is the method to delete multiple object
and 
`Delete.Objects` expect `key:string` but you are giving `key:array` so you need to generate object from your array. I am assuming that `lgfit` is your bucket.

```
const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
    Delete: {
        Objects: [{
                Key: "picture/5b55a7a6c316686bbbbc8120.jpg"
            },
            {
                Key: "picture/5b4c3ca0097c915e38d0d21515-09-2018_12_13_48.jpg"
            }
        ],
        Quiet: false
    }
};
return new Bluebird((resolve) => {
    s3.deleteObjects(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data); // successful response
        /*
        data = {
        Deleted: [
            {
        DeleteMarker: true, 
        DeleteMarkerVersionId: "A._w1z6EFiCF5uhtQMDal9JDkID9tQ7F", 
        Key: "objectkey1"
        }, 
            {
        DeleteMarker: true, 
        DeleteMarkerVersionId: "iOd_ORxhkKe_e8G8_oSGxt2PjsCZKlkt", 
        Key: "objectkey2"
        }
        ]
        }
        */
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It works perfect!!! So I need to remove prefix from the images?

Comment: yes as you are already providing bucket name so you need to give relative path from that bucket root.

Comment: what is `Quiet: false` here?

Comment: The Multi-Object Delete operation supports two modes for the response; verbose and quiet. By default, the operation uses verbose mode in which the response includes the result of deletion of each key in your request. In quiet mode the response includes only keys where the delete operation encountered an error. For a successful deletion, the operation does not return any information about the delete in the response body.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to delete multiple objects using single HTTP request, you should use s3.deleteObjects() instead of s3.deleteObject(). You can try following:

```
var options = {
  Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
  Delete: {
    Objects: [{
      Key: array[0]
    },
    {
      Key: array[1]
    }],
  }
}
return new Bluebird((resolve) => {
  s3.deleteObjects(options, function (err,data){
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data)
  })
})
```

Comment: Now getting this `InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Delete.Objects[0].Key to be a string
`

Comment: I think the problem now is you're providing key as an array where key should be a string and Objects should be an array with multiple keys as the location image object. Have a look here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObjects-property

Comment: Interesting, a slightttttttttt difference between s3.deleteObject() and s3.deleteObjects() kept me thinking even in my dreams. Silly of me and thank you @Ashish

Answer (score 0):

**Change your array as an object**

```
const imgList = [
  {Key: 'picture/5b55a7a6c316686bbbbc8120.jpg'},
  {Key: 'picture/5b4c3ca0097c915e38d0d21515-09-2018_12_13_48.jpg'}
]
```

**Set the array as Objects value in parameters**

```
const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
    Delete: {
        Objects: imgList,
        Quiet: false
    }
};
```

**Now delete objects**

```
return new Bluebird((resolve) => {
    s3.deleteObjects(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data); // successful response
    });
});
```

[Learn more from official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObjects-property)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this method,which allows me to delete single and multiple images both

Suppose I have product and category multiple images ,lets say product consist of 2 images.

here, i will write global function for my delete logic so that i can use this logic wherever i need.

In mine controllers (AWS-s3.js)

```
// global function for deleting image from aws s3
const deleteImageFromAws = async (image) => {
const buckets = {
Bucket: "ultimodeal-image-test",
Key: image,
    };

 s3.deleteObject(buckets, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
  console.log("Error while deleting image from aws s3", err);
  }
  });
 };
```

my product Model (product.Models.js)

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
 name: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  trim: true,
},

price: {
  type: Number,
  required: true,
},
quantity: {
  type: Number,
  required: true,
},
 productPictures: [
// [0]:keys:todo2.png,img:https://mybucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.co/todo2.jpg
//[1] keys:poc2.jpg, img: https://mybucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/poc2.jpg
  {
    keys: {  // for eg: keys:todo2.jpg which is same key from my bucket
      type: String, 
    },
    img: {
      type: String, // for eg: img: https://mybucket.s3.ap-south-   1.amazonaws.com/todo2.jpg
    },
  },
],
const Product = mongoose.model("product", productSchema);
module.exports = Product;
```

Now I have another controllers (Products.Controllers.js) and here i will simply call my global deleting function .So, my image is in array form (that is multiple images) and extracting through map i can delete multiple images in aws-s3.You can see output deleteImage
in response which will show multiple images delete

```
const { deleteImageFromAws } = require("../AWS-S3.Image");// 

exports.deleteProduct = async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const { productId } = req.params;
  const checkProductImage = await Product.findOne({ _id: productId });

if (productId) {
  const removedProduct = await Product.findOneAndDelete({ _id: productId });

  if (!removedProduct) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      status: false,
      message: `The product of id: ${productId} is not available in database`,
    });
  } else {
    const deleteImage = checkProductImage.productPictures.map((image) => {
      deleteImageFromAws(image.keys); // calling deleting function which will delete multiple images
      return image.keys;
    });
    return res.status(200).json({
      status: true,
      message: `The Product with this productId ${productId} is deleted Succesfully...`,
      deleteImage,
    });
  }
} else {
  return res.status(409).json({
    status: false,
    error: "Opps..Cannot deleted",
  });
}
  } catch (error) {
   return res.status(500).json({
  status: false,
  error: error.message,
  });
  }
 };
```

[image: Two Images Deleted from my aws bucket]

Fig:Two images deleted from my aws bucket.If your product models has only 1 image, then it will delete 1 images only for that product Id